# Rotativa works on localhost, shows font as squares on server (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I'm trying to generate a PDF based on a view with Rotativa and save it to Azure storage later. When I test it locally it works, but trying to generate a PDF on the live server doesn't load the font and it only shows as squares. I have tried using multiple simple fonts like Arial, Helvetica, etc, none work.

```
string customSwitches =
    "--header-center \"Document header\" "
    + "--header-font-size \"12\" "
    + "--header-spacing 6 "
    + "--header-font-name \"calibri light\" "
    + "--footer-center \"Page: [page] of 10\" "
    + "--footer-font-size \"11\" "
    + "--footer-spacing 6 "
    + "--footer-font-name \"calibri light\"";

    var file = new PartialViewAsPdf("_GenerateDocument", client) {
                        FileName = filename + extension,
                        RotativaOptions = new Rotativa.Core.DriverOptions()
                        {
                            PageMargins = new Rotativa.Core.Options.Margins
                            {
                                Top = 20,
                                Bottom = 20,
                            },
                            PageOrientation = Rotativa.Core.Options.Orientation.Landscape,
                            CustomSwitches = customSwitches
                        },
                    };
```

This is how it looks on live server:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have faced an issue like this with rotative while using a different font family than system font. the fonts got pixelated. if you are using Azure as a hosting portal then there is a limitation in aZure at present there is no support for GDI.So you can try after changing the font family
please see this
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/12864567-support-for-gdi

Comment: Please add the body of the link into this page, as the forum post may disappear or change over time. For example, suggest how to change the font family to get the result indicated.

Comment: you can use the system default font in your HTML and then check the result use font-family sans-serif, serif, etc..

Answer (score 0):

you can add all design related changes on page level, you cant put all style css at _GenerateDocument page, you will gate result.

Several time CustomSwitches not support css style

Comment: I have both the HTML and CSS in the same _GenerateDocument page, and since it's a pretty simple document, it doesn't link to anything else. I also tried removing the CustomSwitches and the result is the same.

Comment: please make sure rotativa folder with wkhtmltopdf file upload on live server, please remove footer-font-name and Header font name

Comment: The wkhtmltopdf is there, otherwise the pdf wouldn't be created at all. And I tried removing all the custom switches, that means no header no footer, it still gives me square boxes instead of the text.

Comment: then it should be work. make sure both dll on live server Rotativa.core and Rotativa.MVC